# Need help about sending variable from chrome extension to python

Tags: javascript, python, post, google-chrome-extension, download

i wanted to make a small script that download "maps" automatically when the user open the ingame link.
Once the link Open in chrome, the extension get the current URL and send it to python(this is where i'm stuck right now) and then close the tab if successful (since it will fail if the python script isn't running?).
once in python i then proceed to download the map in question and add it to the Songs folder where the only thing he will to do is push F5

right now, i have these pieces of code:

Manifest.json:

```json
{
    "name": "Osu!AltDownload",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A requirement to make osu!AltDownload work",
    "permissions": ["tabs","http://localhost:5000/"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["Osu!AltDownload.js"],
        "persistant": false
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Osu!AltDownload.js

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
        let url = tabs[0].url;
        });
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/",true);
        xhr.send(url); 
    }
})
```

The script that receive the links and download  the "maps":

```py
import browser_cookie3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re
import os
def maplink(osupath):
    link = link #obtain link from POST ?
    if link.split("/",4[:4]) == ['https:', '', 'osu.ppy.sh', 'beatmapsets']:
        Download_map(osupath, link.split("#osu")[0])

def Download_map(osupath, link):
    cj = browser_cookie3.load()
    print("Downloading", link)
    headers = {"referer": link}
    with requests.get(link) as r:
        t = BS(r.text, 'html.parser').title.text.split("·")[0]
    with requests.get(link+"/download", stream=True, cookies=cj, headers=headers) as r:
        if r.status_code == 200:
        try:
            id = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", link)
            with open(os.path.abspath(osupath+"/Songs/"+id+" "+t+".osz"), "wb") as otp:
                otp.write(r.content)
        except:
            print("You either aren't connected on osu!'s website or you're limited by the API, in which case you now have to wait 1h and then try again.")
```

i would like to add in that i used these lines of codes in my extension:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/",true);
xhr.send(url);
```

they come from one of my google searches but i don't really understand how i can handle POST request in python with that and i don't even know if i going the right way.

Some may say i haven't done much research at this subject but out of about 50 chrome tabs, i haven't really found anything that would really give me an idea of the right approach for this subject.

Comment: you have to create web server - ie using web framework like `Flask` or `Django` or eventually using `http.server` - and if it will run on port 5000 then it will receive `http://localhost:5000/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run web server to get `http requests`

You can use `Flask` for this.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print(request.form)
        print(request.data)
    return "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

---

If you want to send only `url` then you can use even `GET` instead of `POST` and send as

```
 http://localhost:5000/?data=your_url
```

where `your_url` is what you get with `tab[0].url`.

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/?data=" + url, true);
xhr.send();  // or maybe xhr.send(null);
```

And then you can get it with

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(request.args.get('data'))
    return "OK"
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example which tests `Flask` using directly `JavaScript` when you visit `http://localhost:5000/test`

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(request.args.get('data'))
    return "OK"

@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    return """
<script>
    var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867136/need-help-about-sending-variable-from-chrome-extension-to-python/";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/?data=" + url, true);
    xhr.send(); 
</script>
"""            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

---

Eventually I can test it with `bookmarklet`

```
javascript:{window.location='http://localhost:5000/?data='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)}
```

which I put as url in bookmark in favorites - but this reload page

or using modern `fetch()` (instead of old `XMLHttpRequest()`) and it doesn't reload page.

```
javascript:{fetch('http://localhost:5000/?data='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href))}
```

Comment: ran this piece of code such as https://pastebin.com/8zCq55VN
while running and then updating the page, i get this as an output `127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2021 17:21:46] "←[33mPOST /data=url HTTP/1.1←[0m" 404 -` and an error occur while executing my extension's code saying url is not defined when the debugger i use in visual code say it does. Here is my extension code rn https://pastebin.com/WufkWnpQ

Comment: sorry, I forgot `?` in `http://localhost:5000/?data=url`

Comment: the extension has the same error `Error in event handler: ReferenceError: url is not defined` even tho i made sure it's var instead or let, but it seem like this wasn't the issue https://pastebin.com/UwCHw0QE

Comment: I don't know full error message - maybe `tabs[0]` don't have `.url`. By the way: it was only example - you have to put real url in place of `url` in data=url` - ie. `"http://localhost:5000/?data=" + url`. And if you send it as `?data=url` then you don't have to send it as `send(url)`. And you have to send it as `GET`, not `POST` because second code doesn't have `methods=['GET', 'POST']` so it has only default `methods=['GET']`

Comment: I don't have Chrome extension so I test `Flask` using web page with `JavaScript` which you can execute with `http://localhost:5000/test` in web browser (after starting `Flask`). See new code in answer

Comment: i remade my extension, replacing xhr which from what i heard from another dev that xhr is ancient here is my new code and i indeed receive the page URL in my python script pastebin.com/RTY2bk0L
i reworked my python script to run other functions with async but there is one last thing i want: i tried running my script in background by renaming with pyw but that doesn't seem to work, is there any other way? (i'm running the pyw from another python script using os.system() and doesn't work)

Comment: I don't use `Winodows`  but Linux and every program runs without displaying terminal. But I wouldn't use `os.system()` to run it but normally `import module` and `module.function()`.

Comment: i'll open another issue since all the attempt at making this webserver run in the background fail

Comment: your "background" rather means "run without displaying terminal". Running in real background means to start it in console without blocking console - so you can execute other commands - and in console you can uses `&` to start any process in background. Other method to run in background is to start it with `cron` or convert to deamon/service - and then it starts automatically when I turn off computer. So describe it correctly in new question.

Comment: issue is that pythonw, .pyw, subprocesses, & and some other that i don't remember, just don't work, so i might have to convert it to a daemon or service like you said